# Ubuntu 9.0.4 Presario S4000NX Fan Speed

Tags: ubuntu, fan

I recently install Ubuntu 9.0.4 on a Presario S4000NX and the CPU fan speed is kept at max.  With Windows XP installed the fan speed would increase/decrease as required.

I've tried to install `lm-sensors` and run the `sensors-detect`.  It recommended that I load the modules which I did:

```
smsc47m192  
i2c-i801
```

When running `sensor-detect` it gave me this strange message:

```
Trying family SMSC
Found SMSC LPC47M15x/192/997 Super IO Fan Sensors
    (but not activated)
```

Running the sensors command gives me a list of voltages and CPU and temperature but doesn't list any fans.

After doing some Internet research I then tried to load the smsc47m1 module but I get the following error:

```
FATAL: Error inserting smsc47m1 (/lib/modules/2.6.28-15-generic/kernel/drivers/hwmon/smsc47m1.ko): no such device
```

The file smsc47m1.ko does exist in the listed folder.

Any suggestions for getting the fan speed (and the noise) down in Ubuntu?

Comment: The `no such device error` indicates it isn't the right module to load, not that the `.ko` isn't found. Do you know if this is a regression? (did you try for example with other linux livecd, one or two years older).

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever updated the BIOS? I don't know if it helps (or if there's a newer BIOS available for your system) in your case, but for example with my Dell Latitude D830 laptop the original BIOS version caused deadlocks during docking/undocking, WLAN didn't work very reliably and so on. With the later revisions everything's been fine.

Also, upgrading to Ubuntu 10.04 would be a good idea.